# why list printout is in reverse like the list is starting from the bottom of the screen going up?

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

Hi I am just wondering why this is happening basically I have a
array adapter that prints out a array of strings in a list view but
I don't know why list printout is in reverse like the list
is starting from the bottom of the screen going up ? I want the list going from the top -down so does anyone have an idea.
Please help me....:)

Answer (score 0):

if you are setting any of these property into your Xml file please remove it to return listview to its normal status.

```
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="normal"
```